# Prevent registry key from auto delete on restart

Tags: powershell, windows-7, registry

I'm using PowerShell to create an AutoLogon instance after imaging a machine with Windows 7. The script is designed to automate the process for installing an encryption software which requires a reboot. Here is the script I have thus far.

```
#Registry path declaration
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
$RegROPath = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

Write-Host "Installing Encryption."
Write-Host "Please note that a reboot is required to complete the installation process."
Write-Host "Enter the local administrator credentials when promoted!"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)

Clear

#Get Auto Logon credentials.
$credential = Get-Credential $env:username

#Install 01_ClientPreinstall then restart the computer
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\encrypt_installer\01_ClientPreinstall.msi" -argumentlist "/passive" -Wait

#Set registry properties for auto logon
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -Type String
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUserName" -Value $credential.GetNetworkCredential().username -Type String
New-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value $credential.GetNetworkCredential().password -Type String

#Add script to registry to continue after logon
New-ItemProperty $RegROPath "Continue" -Value "C:\encrypt_installer\sre02.bat" -Type String

Restart-Computer -Force
```

The problem I'm having is, the script runs and adds the values to the registry:

[image]

but when the computer restarts, it does not log in. I have to log in manually.

I verified that the password was correct by commenting out the restart, going to the registry and looking at the value, then manually restart. If I run the script again when I log in, it goes through the exact same process, however, this time it will Auto Log on. So after the image, I tried restarting the machine first before running the script, but it still does not work.

I found out that the `DefaulPassword` registry key is being removed automatically when the computer restarts for the first time after running the script. Is there a way to possibly prevent this from happening?

It's worth noting that the `DefaultPassword` key is not present in the registry by default, though I know that can be gleaned from the `New-ItemProperty` call in the script.

Comment: We sell an authentication software package for windows. We have, ever since the XP days, used the auto logon Default(username, password, domainname) values for not only autologon but for logging users in generically.

Seemingly from nowhere and specifically on windows 10, the DefaultDomainName and DefaultUserName Fields are being deleted upon reboot.
Not sure if related but thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: I know this is years old, but to anyone stumbling over this I wanted to say that I have the exact same problem, only for a different key (AutoAdminLogon and DefaultDomainName). The other Keys are still there after rebooting. If anyone has a solution please tell me